# How can I show Facebook link in a grid?

Tags: html, css, iframe, grid, division

I need help with this `<iframe>`, I can't insert into the grid layout. I can insert the `<iframe>` to every part of the website except this grid layout.

Thank you for any help.

```css
.lluncamp2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.lluncamp2 img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lluncamp2">

  <div>
    <ul>Laundry room-
      <li>Coin operated Washing machine</li>
      <li>Tumble dryer</li>
      <li>FREE Fridge/ Freezer</li>
      <li>Shaving and electricity points</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?height=314&href=https%3A%2
      F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkosmic.suture%2Fvideos%2F1936825236449065%2F&show_text=false&width=560" max-width="560" max-height="314" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write;
      encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe></div>
  <div>Ample field space to enjoy and play</div>
  <div>Chemical disposal point</div>
  <div>FREE hot water in both the showers and dishwashing room</div>
  <div>Coin operated launderette</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried to improve your question, but please could you take a look and ensure that it still asks the correct question, because I'm personally struggling to work out what your specific question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is your actual HTML, then the problem is the line break on your src attribute of the iframe tag. It runs fine for me if I change your iframe to:

```css
.lluncamp2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.lluncamp2 img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lluncamp2">

  <div>
    <ul>Laundry room-
      <li>Coin operated Washing machine</li>
      <li>Tumble dryer</li>
      <li>FREE Fridge/ Freezer</li>
      <li>Shaving and electricity points</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?height=314&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkosmic.suture%2Fvideos%2F1936825236449065%2F&show_text=false&width=560" max-width="560" max-height="314" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write;
      encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe></div>
  <div>Ample field space to enjoy and play</div>
  <div>Chemical disposal point</div>
  <div>FREE hot water in both the showers and dishwashing room</div>
  <div>Coin operated launderette</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i feel ashamed. so tired i couldn't write the question out properly.